# Formatting yyyymmdd varchar column to Month, Day Year in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a simple query shown below.  I am trying to format the column yyyymmdd to Month, Day, Year format. How can do this?

The yyyymmdd returns 2015-11-13 00:00:00.000
            I would like it to return November 13, 2015

```
SELECT
      CONVERT(datetime, yyyymmdd, 101)  as 'Date of Data',

        cd.[text] as 'Last POS Upload Time Each Day'

FROM MyTable CD 
  WHERE     CD.[Store] = @Store
        AND YYYYMMDD between @Beginning_Date AND @Ending_Date
        AND [text] <> '' 

group by  cd.[Store], [text], cd.[yyyymmdd]
order by  cd.[store], cd.[yyyymmdd], [text]
```

Comment: Always try to include your rdbms tag for sql questions `SqlServer`, `MySql`?. Some functions arent available on all databases.

Comment: I assume it's SQL-Server as this is tagged as such. Please see http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: Best solution here is, of course, to **fix the schema!**

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Do you miss a link? I dont see how is that helpfull

Comment: Later versions of Sql Server have a `format` function. What's your version?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza what Joel meant was that storing datetime data in a datetime datatype is by far the best way to fix this. Storing it in some other datatype "with a format" is highly prone to error. If this was stored in the correct datatype there wouldn't be a need for a question.

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry I disagree, Sometime you cant change the schema, and even if you have the data in a datetime sometime you still need to format to the want you need.

Comment: Of course you can't always change the schema but that really would be the best fix. And really any kind of formatting should be done in the front end. If you format it in sql it makes things like sorting a lot more difficult in the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a built in function that returns exactly what you're looking for, but you always have the option to roll it yourself...

```
SELECT
        DATENAME(month, yyyymmdd) + ' ' +
        CONVERT(nvarchar(50), DATEPART(day, yyyymmdd)) + ', ' + 
        CONVERT(nvarchar(50), DATEPART(Year, yyyymmdd)) AS [Your Date In Your Format],
...rest of your query
```

Here's a [proof of concept sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/3887).

Comment: Thanks LDMJoe...I am getting an incorrect syntax error near 'max'

Comment: You didn't specify what version of SQL Server.  Is there a version that doesn't support the `nvarchar(max)` data type?  Try replacing the max with like 50 or something - for this application that should still be plenty long enough.  It for sure works when just done locally - I updated the question to include a fiddle as proof of concept.

Comment: Sorry, it is SQL 2000 and changing it to 50 worked great!  Thanks!

Comment: @BradJarrett I updated the answer.  I saw you accepted a different answer, but I'd still take an upvote if it worked!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
SELECT DATENAME(MM, yyyymmdd) + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), yyyymmdd, 107), 9) AS 'Date of Data',
```

Comment: Thanks Mattia, I tried it, but I get this November20151113

Answer (score 0):

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0bdb4/1)**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([MyDate] datetime);

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([MyDate])
VALUES
    ('2015-11-13 00:00:00');

SELECT DATENAME(MM, MyDate) + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), MyDate, 107), 9) AS [Month DD, YYYY]
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT 
      DATENAME(MM, '2015-11-13 00:00:00.000')
      + ' '  + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '2015-11-13 00:00:00.000', 107), 2)
      + ', ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4) , '2015-11-13 00:00:00.000', 107), 9) AS 'FormattedDate'
```

Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Please mark as solution if this solved the problem. I am hoping to build my reputation on the stackoverflow.

Comment: This worked great!  I also used LDMJoe's solution and it worked identical.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am glad it worked. I am new to stackoverflow so there are lots of restrictions for me. Can you mark my answer as a solution and also give a thumb up? So I can earn some reputation.